# Google Analytics Events are Not Registering

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, google-tag-manager, custom-events, google-optimize

I am in need of assistance. I am trying to implement Custom Event Tracking for a form submission as both an Analytics Goal, and a Conversion Goal for Google Optimize.

Here is a screenshot of the Google Analytics Goal:

[image]

I have my Google Analytics in the head (with sensitive information redacted with XXXXX) as such:

```
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=XXXXXXXXXXX"></script>
<script>
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
gtag('js', new Date());

gtag('config', 'XXXXXXXXXXX', { 'optimize_id': 'XXXXXXXXXXX'});
</script>
```

And then I have tried to fire the custom event with both:

```
ga('send', {
 hitType: 'event',
 eventCategory: 'mailchimp',
 eventAction: 'subscribe',
 eventLabel: 'soft-lead-form'
});
```

and also:

```
gtag('event', 'play', {
 'event_category': 'mailchimp',
 'event_label': 'soft-lead-form'
});
```

I have confirmed that analytics is instanced effectively by writing to the console with:

```
if (gtag) {
 console.log("ga present");
}
```

And I have confirmed that the user action triggers the ga call by writing to the console in the same function with:

```
$("#mc-embedded-subscribe-form").submit(function(){
   gtag('event', 'play', {
   'event_category': 'mailchimp',
   'event_label': 'soft-lead-form'
  });
  console.log("ga Event Submitted");
 });
```

I would GREATLY APPRECIATE any help. I've been through pages of documentation and, despite trying/testing multiple points in this process, I can not get the event to appear in Either Analytics or Optimize. This is a crucial piece for our marketing efforts and I very much want to make it work.

Thank you so much!
Gary

Comment: Could you share an URL where this form is accessible?

Answer (score 1):

Surely the event with `ga(...)` you have to remove it because you are using **gtag**.

If you are seeing the events real time, then you need to wait for at least 24-72 hrs to get the data updated under Behaviour -> Events -> Overview.